# Spark1.4.0 cannot connect to Hbase 1.1.0.1

Tags: apache-spark, hbase

it raise the error

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Addressing.getIpAddress()Ljava/net/InetAddress;

while I can success connect to hbase by using spark shell. could anyone knows where the problem is?

the detail error

```
15/07/01 18:57:57 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:240)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:218)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:119)
    at com.koudai.resys.tmp.HbaseLearning$.main(HbaseLearning.scala:22)
    at com.koudai.resys.tmp.HbaseLearning.main(HbaseLearning.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:483)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:238)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Addressing.getIpAddress()Ljava/net/InetAddress;
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientIdGenerator.getIpAddressBytes(ClientIdGenerator.java:83)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientIdGenerator.generateClientId(ClientIdGenerator.java:43)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.PerClientRandomNonceGenerator.<init>(PerClientRandomNonceGenerator.java:37)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(ConnectionManager.java:682)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(ConnectionManager.java:630)
    ... 14 more
```

the sbt config:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.4.0" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "1.4.0" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase" % "1.1.0.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-client" % "1.1.0.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-common" % "1.1.0.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-server" % "1.1.0.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-hadoop2-compat" % "1.1.0.1"
```

the running code:

> ```
>     val sc =  new SparkConf().setAppName("hbase@user")
>     val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
>     conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181")
>     conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "idc02-rs-sfa-10")
>
>     // the error raised from here
>     val conn = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf)
> ```

using reflection to list the methods for org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Addressing found it is hbase 0.94 version, where could be it from?

```
parsePort
createHostAndPortStr
createInetSocketAddressFromHostAndPortStr
getIpAddress
getIp4Address
getIp6Address
parseHostname
isLocalAddress
wait
wait
wait
equals
toString
hashCode
getClass
notify
notifyAll
```

Comment: You just need hbase-client in your app. Why are you including hbase-server, hbase-common in your app? Are you using cdh or hdp? Which version of distro? Also, what is the classpath of your app at runtime? Any stale installation library of hbase being referenced there?

Comment: thanks，1. hbase-common is also need by tested  2. using Apache origin version 2.5.2 , 3. classpath already contains hadoop lib  4. you are right, by dig into the classpath, found someone accidently put an old version hbase lib (0.94) into hadoop library, which polluted the classpath

Answer (score 0):

The problems is classpath conflict, somewhere exist hbase-0.94 which conflict with hbase-1.1.0.1

provided  way how to identify such problems for others:

way 1: using reflection to identify the class

```
  val methods = new org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Addressing().getClass.getMethods
  methods.foreach(method=>println(method.getName))
```

way 2: print classpath on cloud node to debug

```
    def urlses(cl: ClassLoader): Array[java.net.URL] = cl match {
        case null => Array()
        case u: java.net.URLClassLoader => u.getURLs() ++ urlses(cl.getParent)
        case _ => urlses(cl.getParent)
    }

    val  urls = urlses(getClass.getClassLoader)
    urls.foreach(url=>println(url.toString))
```